# my blog writing input is removing last line in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

[image]

this is the current state where I have 4 lines and 5th line in current input

and this is my react code

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface BlogWitterProps {}

const BlogWitter: FC<BlogWitterProps> = ({}) => {
  const [markdownContent, setMarkdownContent] = useState("");
  const [currentLine, setCurrentLine] = useState("");

  // on each new line, update the markdown content

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("markdownContent", markdownContent);
    console.log("currentLine", currentLine);
  }, [currentLine, markdownContent]);

  const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      setMarkdownContent((prev) => {
        return prev + currentLine + "\n";
      });
      setCurrentLine("");
    } else if (e.key === "Backspace" && currentLine === "") {
      e.preventDefault();
      setMarkdownContent((prev) => {
        const lines = prev.split("\n");
        const lastLine = lines.pop();
        console.log("lines", lines);

        setTimeout(() => {
          // If the last line is not empty, update the current line state
          if (lastLine !== "") {
            setCurrentLine(lastLine + "\n");
          } else {
            setCurrentLine("");
          }
        }, 0);

        return lines.join("\n");
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div>
        {markdownContent.split("\n").map((line, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              {line}
              <br />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <input
        value={currentLine}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCurrentLine(e.target.value);
        }}
        className="w-full resize-none outline-none text-2xl bg-transparent border border-black"
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogWitter;
```

so if I press backspace and it takes me to last line to edit then press anter again without changing anything it is remove the last line's new line and gives me this

[image]

I am trying to get it to work as in medieum where you can edit each line seperatly

Comment: I ran your file and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of events is easier to understand when the character codes for `markdownContent` are printed to the console.

Below, I've re-pasted the code, with some test code in place (LINES 16-21) to display `markdownContent` as a series of ASCII character codes separated by the pipe (|) character.

### Key sequences and markdownContent char codes

| step | key sequence | input field | char codes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A + Enter | A | 65 | 10 |
| 2 | B + Enter | B | 65 | 10 | 66 | 10 |
| 3 | C + Enter | C | 65 | 10 | 66 | 10 | 67 | 10 |
| 4 | Backspace |  | 65 | 10 | 66 | 10 | 67 |
| 5 | Backspace | C | 65 | 10 | 66 |
| 6 | Enter |  | 65 | 10 | 66 | 67 | 10 | 10 |

### Stepping through the code

At **step 4**, pressing Backspace executes LINE 33. This splits the character codes in **step 3** by chr(10) (linefeed). LINE 34 pops the last character (linefeed), and LINE 42 discards it since the input text field is blank (`setCurrentLine("")` is called).

At **step 5** Backspace is pressed again (because the input field did not move after **step 4**). LINE 33 is executed again, splitting the characters in **step 4** by linefeed, popping chr(67) (letter *C*) at LINE 34, and discarding *C*. The input form field is blank just prior to pressing Backspace, causing `setCurrentLine("")` to be called. *C* is discarded from `markdownContent` but is re-added to the input text field.

At **step 6** Enter is pressed causing the problem described in the question. Here, the characters in **step 5** are joined with `currentLine`: (*C*) + Enter (the Enter key just pressed). This is where the letters **BC** are joined together. The original linefeed that would have separated these two characters is consumed by the call to `split()` at **step 5** in LINE 33. LINE 27 adds a second linefeed. This is why we see two linefeeds at **step 6**.

### Notes

There are several cases and edge cases that need to be considered before text input will behave correctly.

### Code

```
1.    import * as React from "react";
2.
3.    const { useEffect, useState } = React;
4.
5.    interface BlogWitterProps {}
6.
7.    const BlogWitter: React.FunctionComponent<BlogWitterProps> = ({}) => {
8.      const [markdownContent, setMarkdownContent] = useState("");
9.      const [currentLine, setCurrentLine] = useState("");
10.
11.      // on each new line, update the markdown content
12.
13.      useEffect(() => {
14.        console.log("markdownContent", markdownContent);
15.        console.log("currentLine", currentLine);
16.        let chars = [];
17.        for ( let c of markdownContent ) {
18.            chars.push( c.charCodeAt( 0 ) );
19.        }
20.        let codeString = chars.join('|');
21.        console.log( 'codes: ' + codeString );
22.      }, [currentLine, markdownContent]);
23.
24.      const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
25.        if (e.key === "Enter") {
26.          setMarkdownContent((prev) => {
27.            return prev + currentLine + "\n";
28.          });
29.          setCurrentLine("");
30.        } else if (e.key === "Backspace" && currentLine === "") {
31.          e.preventDefault();
32.          setMarkdownContent((prev) => {
33.            const lines = prev.split("\n");
34.            const lastLine = lines.pop();
35.            console.log("lines", lines);
36.
37.            setTimeout(() => {
38.              // If the last line is not empty, update the current line state
39.              if (lastLine !== "") {
40.                setCurrentLine(lastLine + "\n");
41.              } else {
42.                setCurrentLine("");
43.              }
44.            }, 0);
45.
46.            return lines.join("\n");
47.          });
48.        }
49.      };
50.
51.      return (
52.        <div className="">
53.          <div>
54.            {markdownContent.split("\n").map((line, index) => {
55.              return (
56.                <div key={index}>{ line }</div>
57.              );
58.            })}
59.          </div>
60.          <input
61.            value={currentLine}
62.            size={ 80 }
63.            onChange={(e) => {
64.              setCurrentLine(e.target.value);
65.            }}
66.            className="w-full resize-none outline-none text-2xl bg-transparent border border-black"
67.            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
68.          />
69.        </div>
70.      );
71.    };
72.
73.    export default BlogWitter;
```

Comment: Hi @ibo. Adding **console.log** statements to your code for step-by-step debugging can lead to dead code. **console.log** can be avoided by using Debugging tools. Firefox Developer Tools has a Debugging tab. You can set [Watch Expressions](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/how_to/set_watch_expressions/index.html) and Breakpoints. For example, you can get **char code** output with this Watch Expression: `[...markdownContent].map(function(c){return c.charCodeAt(0);}).join(' | ')`. Your bundler might have to produce sourcemaps in developer mode to make this work.